# Get rid of [Pipeline] messages in the console output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job on Jenkins that pulls a repo with a Jenkinsfile that defines the stages of the pipeline. There are multiple stages with huge logs and I don't want to see the numerous [Pipeline] messages that are displayed at the beginning of each stage and at the end. Instead it would be helpful to have a small banner or header of a single line for each stage just to differentiate. Could someone suggest a possible way of doing this?

Basically trying to get rid of these lines:

[Pipeline] {

[Pipeline] stage

[Pipeline] { (Build)

[Pipeline] ......

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // stage

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] End of Pipeline

Comment: [JENKINS-45210](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45210) requested for that.

Comment: yes the issue still seems to be unresolved. An alternative that I found helpful was the "Collapsing Console Sections" plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Collapsing+Console+Sections+Plugin). Although it is not what I was looking for, it serves the purpose at the moment. The pipeline messages are still visible in the console output but can be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Install the plugin

https://plugins.jenkins.io/simple-theme-plugin/

Goto Manage Jenkins -> Configure System

Add Extra CSS under the section "Theme"

Paste the below code

```
.pipeline-annotated {
     display: none; 
}
.pipeline-new-node {
      display: none; 
}
```